# Guava Mutlimap to HashMap

Tags: java, collections, guava

is it possible in any way to cast Multimap to HashMap. I know we can convert multimap to map, but i want to convert multimap to hashmap. I don't think its possible but if there is any way out, please let me know.

Comment: You can't _cast_ a `Multimap` to a `HashMap` since as - the names indicate - they are different things. You can call `asMap()` on the `Multimap` though and if you want to make sure it's a `HashMap`, try `Maps.newHashMap( multimap.asMap() )`. One note though: you'll get a `Map<K, Collection<V>>` so if you by any chance are after a `Map<K, V>` be warned that this is likely to result in loss of data (multimaps exist for a reason).

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Thomas Why don't you provide your comment as an answer?

Comment: @mfulton26 you're right, I'll change that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it possible in any way to cast Multimap to HashMap.

No, you can't *cast* a Multimap to a HashMap since - as the names indicate - they are different things, i.e. a `Multimap` is meant to map *multiple* values to a key while a `Map` is meant to map *one* value to a key. Hence converting a `Multimap<K, V>` to a `Map` would always yield something like `Map<K, Collection<V>>` (or, depending in the actual `Multimap` implementation and by using some other method a `Map<K, List<V>>` etc.).

> I know we can convert multimap to map, but i want to convert multimap to hashmap.

You're probably referring to the `asMap()` method which returns a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`. Those probably aren't instances of `HashMap` but you can easily create one by calling `Maps.newHashMap( multimap.asMap() )` which basically takes the generated map and copies the values (references) to a new `HashMap`.

Comment: `No, you can't cast a Multimap to a HashMap since - the names indicate - they are different things` lol - makes no sense. You can cast `Exception` to `RunTimeException`.

Comment: @xenteros No you can't, `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`, not the other way around. As for the answer, it clearly means that `Multimap` and `Map` are unrelated interfaces, as developed right after.

Comment: @xenteros `RuntimeException` _is an_ `Exception` and hence the case works (although not necessarily in both directions depending on the actual implementation). However `Multimap` and `Map` are different things and share no common hierarchy (except `Object` ofc). Just that they are both maps doesn't mean you can _cast_ them.

Comment: I'm just showing you that the argument was stupid. Why would you judge about functionalities basing on class names

Comment: @xenteros because that's what people normally do: they select class names that provide as much information on the intended use and functionality as possible. And since `Map` and all implementations are commonly used in the Java world every dev should know the basic property of those maps: one value per key (which I also explained in the second part of that sentence, the difference I was getting at is the part "multi" in the name `Multimap`).

Comment: @xenteros I also emphasized the word _cast_ since that's what the sentence was getting at: you can't _cast_ as the OP asked for but you can _convert_.